# Связывание ViewHolder вместе с GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно связывать ViewHolder вместе с GridView и его действиями, скажем, простенький пример, если можно, для понимания структуры.

Comment: Вы воспользовались поиском прежде, чем задавать вопрос?

Comment: @metalurgus да, но там не совсем те примеры который я хотел бы видеть)

Comment: То есть вы сейчас предлагаете нам поугадывать, какой же все-таки пример вы хотите видеть? А приз будет тому, кто угадает?

Answer (score 1):

`ViewHolder` это объект, держащий ссылки на поля - поскольку метод `findViewById()` очень ресурсо-затратный. `GridView` это компоновщик лаяута.

Все, что вам нужно знать о "связывании" этих двух вещей:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);


// Используйте этот метод, если уверены, что размер адаптера не будет меняться

mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

// Первый входной параметр это контекст, второй количество колонок.

GridLayoutManager glm=new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

// Программно устанавливаете компоновщик (тут и происходит "связывание" в вашем понимании)

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);

// Создаете инстанс ресайклера

mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(myDataset);

// Устанавливаете адаптер к ресайклервью

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример для ListView, думаю для GridView он тоже подойдет!

```
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mData;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, String[] objects) {
        mContext = context;
        mData = objects;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtItem;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int i) {
        return mData[i];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtItem.setText(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.length;
    }
}
```